Character count in user input in assembly language
I am trying to prompt the user to enter an ID which can be in length from 1 to 30 characters. It can be both letters and numbers, but limited to 30 characters. Below is my code and it's showing error for any ID I enter (like if I enter '123helo', it's showing me error).
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc 

.data
IDprompt BYTE " ENter ID: ",0
InvalidId BYTE " ID you entered is not valid ",0


.code 
Main Proc 
call ID_check

exitProgram:
exit 
Main ENDP

ID_check PROC
    Mov edx, OFFSET newline
    call WriteString 
    mov edx, OFFSET IDprompt   ; Display prompt for student ID
    call WriteString
    
    mov edx, OFFSET id  ; Buffer for student ID
    mov ecx, 31         ; Maximum characters to read including null terminator 
    call ReadString 
             
    cmp byte ptr [id], 0       ; Check for null input and re-prompt if empty
    je  ID_check               ; Ask to enter ID again if left null
    
    ; Null-terminate the ID buffer after reading
    movzx ebx, byte ptr [id]   ; Get the length of the input
    mov byte ptr [id + ebx], 0 ; Null-terminate the string
    
    cmp ebx, 1    ; Check if input is less than 1 character
    jl id_invalid
    cmp ebx, 30   ; Check if input is more than 30 characters (including null terminator)
    jg  id_invalid 
            
    ret

id_invalid:
    Mov edx, OFFSET newline
    call WriteString 
    mov edx, OFFSET invalidId
    call WriteString
    jmp ID_check

ID_check  ENDP

END Main 



“showing me error” is not a good error description.  What is the exact error message that is shown?

ReadString returns the number of bytes in eax not in the first byte of the buffer. Also it zero terminates the string for you.

fuz- showing error means, on any input its going to id_invalid: and printing a InvalidID msg,
-- jester- does that mean I need to compare with eax , did that also but still not checking the length and still accepts more than 30 characters.

Since you pass the length to ReadString it will never overfill your buffer. You can ask for 32 characters (1 for the terminator) and then you can see if you get more than 30.


cmp byte ptr [id], 0       ; Check for null input and re-prompt if empty
je  ID_check               ; Ask to enter ID again if left null

; Null-terminate the ID buffer after reading
movzx ebx, byte ptr [id]   ; Get the length of the input
mov byte ptr [id + ebx], 0 ; Null-terminate the string

cmp ebx, 1    ; Check if input is less than 1 character
jl id_invalid
cmp ebx, 30   ; Check if input is more than 30 characters (including null terminator)
jg  id_invalid 


Even if you believed that ReadString returns with the length stored in the first byte, then:

cmp ebx, 1 would be a redundant operation since the first byte was already established to contain a 1 or more.
cmp ebx, 30 would be redundant since you already restricted the input to 31 (including the terminator), so never more than 30 characters.
Please note that in case you didn't trust ReadString on this, it would not be prudent to have that mov byte ptr [id + ebx], 0 before you did your own testing.

From Irvine Library Help:

ReadString reads a string of up to ECX non-null characters from standard input, stopping when the user presses the Enter key.
A null byte is stored following the characters input, but the trailing carriage return and line feed characters are not placed into the buffer.
ECX should always be smaller than the buffer size (never equal to the buffer size) because the null byte could be the (ECX+1)th character stored.
Call args:  EDX points to the input buffer, ECX max number of non-null chars to read
Return arg: EAX = size of input string.

You want to restrict the input to just 30 characters. Therefore specify ECX=30 and have a buffer prepared for 31 bytes. You don't need to zero-terminate yourself. EAX will hold a value from 0 to 30.
mov  edx, OFFSET id ; Buffer for student ID
mov  ecx, 30        ; Max chars to read EXCLUDING null terminator 
call ReadString
test eax, eax       ; Check for null input and re-prompt if empty
jz   ID_check       ; Ask to enter ID again if left null

